# What guarantees of enum compactness does the Rust ABI make?

Tags: rust

I understand that the Rust ABI is not stable. However, the Rust compiler currently performs some optimizations to compact fields into tags. [For example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=eb4a0f2f38311ff763d365e965e1541a&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015):

```
use std::mem::size_of;

enum Node {
    N1_1 {
        is_good: bool,
        stuff: u32,
    },
    N1_2 {
        is_good: bool,
        left: Box<Node>,
        right: Box<Node>,
    },
}

enum Node2 {
    N2_1 { stuff: u32 },
    N2_2,
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?} {:?}", size_of::<Node>(), size_of::<Node2>());
}
```

This prints `24 8`. Clearly what is happening is that the fields are getting folded into the constructor tags. Is this behavior guaranteed? I'm not asking if the specific memory representation will stay the same but whether there is a promise that the size at some future point in time will not increase.

I can't think of a good reason why they may want to change the representation at some point to increase sizes, but maybe it is just my lack of imagination, so I'm looking for an "official" answer.

Links to GitHub issues/RFCs would be helpful. I tried browsing the issue tracker but wasn't able to find anything. The closest thing I could find was related to a `bool` being 1 byte sized, which isn't guaranteed.

Comment: The compiler *does* perform enum optimization by niche-filling ([related](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/46213)), but I don't think your example demonstrates that. `Node` can't take advantage of niche-filling (as currently implemented) because it doesn't have any zero-sized variants; `Node2` has a zero-sized variant, but the non-zero-sized variant doesn't have any invalid values to fit it into. What do you mean by "the fields are getting folded into the constructor tags"?

Comment: @trentcl, the tag has padding bytes because of alignment requirements. For example, if I'd used `N1_1(Box<Node1>, Box<Node1>`, the size would've still been 24 bytes, with 7 bytes of padding for the tag. What's happening with the `bool` is that that one padding byte is getting replaced with the bool. Trying using `#[repr(C)]` and you'll see that the size jumps to 32.

Comment: Rust does not "fill in" the padding bytes of a sibling type with values of another. This would allow two mutable references to the same memory address.

Comment: I'm very confused then. What is the memory layout of `Node1` in that case? @Shepmaster, could you add that to your answer?

Comment: I see what you mean, but it's not accurate to say that the *tag* has padding bytes. The *variants* have padding which may be different for different variants, but that is a consequence of how the memory layout is calculated. The padding in a variant does not need to be adjacent to the tag at all, and may exist even when the tag is absent. [In this example you can see that the tag is placed before `x`, but the padding is placed between `y` and `z`.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=90f395959ed46ee173f9312c4f6b2967&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this behavior guaranteed?

No. The Rust ABI makes **no guarantees of any kind**, that's what "unstable" means. So long as the code works and other guarantees outside of the ABI are held, the developers are able to change it however they see fit.

Really, in this case you don't care so much about the ABI as you do the [type layout](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html). The reference says, emphasis mine:

> Nominal types without a `repr` attribute have the default representation. Informally, this representation is also called the `rust` representation.
>
> There are **no guarantees of data layout made by this representation**.

> a good reason why they may want to change the representation at some point to increase sizes

One possible reason is because of concepts like padding or alignment. It's possible (but unlikely) that someone discovers that aligning every struct to 331 bytes makes code run 53x faster.

---

```
rustc +nightly -Zprint-type-sizes enum-compactness.rs
```

```
type: `Node`: 24 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
    discriminant: 1 bytes
    variant `N1_1`: 7 bytes
        field `.is_good`: 1 bytes
        padding: 2 bytes
        field `.stuff`: 4 bytes, alignment: 4 bytes
    variant `N1_2`: 23 bytes
        field `.is_good`: 1 bytes
        padding: 6 bytes
        field `.left`: 8 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
        field `.right`: 8 bytes
```

```
type: `Node2`: 8 bytes, alignment: 4 bytes
    discriminant: 4 bytes
    variant `N2_1`: 4 bytes
        field `.stuff`: 4 bytes
    variant `N2_2`: 0 bytes
```