# Why does switching from struct to enum breaks API, exactly?

Tags: rust

I encountered an interesting change [in a public PR](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/pull/588).
Initially they had:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Copy)]
pub struct ParseError(ParseErrorKind);

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Copy)]
enum ParseErrorKind {
    OutOfRange // ... omitting other values here to be short
}
```

`ParseError` cannot be instantiated by clients because `ParseErrorKind` is private. They are making that `enum` public now, which seems ok, but I suggested an alternative: have `ParseError` be an `enum` itself, and leverage the type system instead of imitating it with the notion of "kind". They told me that would be an API breakage, and therefore was not ok.

I think I understand why in theory a `struct` and an `enum` are different. But I am not sure to understand why it is incompatible in this precise case.

Since the `struct ParseError` had no mutable field and cannot be instantiated by clients, there was nothing we could do with the type but to assign it and compare it. It seems both `struct` and `enum` support that, so client code is unlikely to require a change to compile with a newer version exposing an `enum` instead of `struct`. Or did I miss another use we could have with the `struct`, that would result in requiring a change in client code?

However there might be an ABI incompatibility too. How does Rust handle the `struct` in practice, knowing that only the library can construct it? Is there any sort of allocation or deallocation mechanism that requires to know precisely what `ParseError` is made of at buildtime? And does switching from that exact `struct` to an `enum` impact that? Or could it be safe in this particular case? And is that relevant to try to maintain the ABI since [it is not guaranteed so far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51340645/what-guarantees-of-enum-compactness-does-the-rust-abi-make)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because every `struct` has fields, and hence this pattern will work for any `struct`, but will not compile with an `enum`:

```rs
struct Foo {}

fn returns_a_foo() -> Foo {
  // anything that may return a Foo
}

if let Foo { .. } = returns_a_foo() {}
```

For example, this code compiles:

```rs
fn main() {
    if let String { .. } = String::new() {}
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=97e4beff4f0bfc475674920c6338be95).

And while probably not code you'd write on your own, it's still possible to write, and additionally, possible to generate through a macro. Note that this is then, obviously, not compatible with an `enum` pattern match:

```rs
if let Option { .. } = None {
    // Compile error.
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=16fc1b8fac8e26df5cccf5dd8bf85139).

Comment: If `Foo` was an `enum`, we wouldn't be able to write this because we would have to instantiate a particular value of it, and not just a `Foo`, right?

Comment: Anyways `ParseError` here does not have `new` in my case, so I'll share a playground in the question to show the initial state.

Comment: @VictorPaléologue The use of a function called `new` here is not the point. You can match any struct value, regardless of construction, in this fashion. Making it an enum would break that. Try making your suggested change here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=020440b206d25a4b50e09e57ec9fabf3

Comment: But can client code write that pattern if the type of the field of the `struct` is private?

Comment: @VictorPaléologue yes, I did it with `String` in my post and `String` has no public fields.

Comment: My question is about the _type_ of the field, rather than just the field. But perhaps one implies that the other is moot?

Comment: @VictorPaléologue Yes, one can write patterns which involve public fields, however private fields can only be written as `..` since you can't name them. Additionally, you cannot make a public field with a private type.

Comment: Ok thanks. Even though in that specific case using this pattern would be pointless, it is formally valid code, and it would be broken if `ParseError` became an `enum`.